# jQuery confirm box that pauses script execution

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a jquery/nice looking alternative to the standard dialog box. jQUery UI has a nice one, but it doesn't pause script execution to wait for the response like confirm() does. The demo below is supposed to display two divs that display the choice of the preceding confirm box, but the jquery dialog box doesn't cause the script to wait.

http://jsfiddle.net/EvilAmarant7x/r7Ur5/

I specifically need something that causes the script to pause.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your using the dialog in the wrong way

you should do it like this

```
 $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
resizable: false,
height: 140,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    Proceed: function() {
          call_true_function();
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        call_false_function()
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
});
```

or something similar

** EDIT **

so something like this ?

```
count = 0;
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
resizable: false,
height: 140,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    Proceed: function() {
          proceed();
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
});

function proceed(){
    if (count < 10){
        count++;
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');    
    }else{
        $('body').append("<div>Yes was selected " + count + " times!</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: @mcgrailm While I realize that this is the way dialog is supposed to be used, that implementation doesn't lend itself very well to giving a user a series of questions and then performing some action based on the aggregate response. Or maybe I'm just missing it. I can't think of a way, at least not without doing something like having the callback functions be Call_Question_N+1(), which creates the next in the series of dialogs. Which seems like an obtuse solution for something normally implemented like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EvilAmarant7x/r7Ur5/4/)

Comment: @EvilAmarant7x indeed it is, however unfortunately that's just the nature of the beast. You cannot just halt javascript execution. There is no pause, sleep, or wait feature in javascript. The best you can do is use a delegate or event callback. There are some ways of making this *look* better for a long series of questions, but fundamentally they are all doing the same thing.

Comment: I'll just add to that that a long series of yes/no questions is probably not the best interface design choice either. Users are likely to accidentally give the same answer twice for example or not remember or see what they just answered yes to. You might try a jQuery modal with radio buttons instead if you've got several yes/no questions to ask.

Comment: also note in the second example you could change the content of the dialog before you opened it each time

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, this is not possible if you use a custom confirm/modal window. You're going to have to use callbacks or opt to use the new [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object introduced with 1.5.

Using deferred would look something like this:

```
var dfd = new $.Deferred();
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height: 140,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Proceed: function() {
        dfd.resolve('Success!');
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        dfd.reject('Uh-oh!');
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});

dfd.then(function() {
  // perform next action when user clicks proceed
});

dfd.fail(function() {
  // perform some action when the user clicks cancel
});
```